# Expose Kube API to outside network

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes cluster installed inside a VM on AWS EC2. When I try getting the Kube API URL, I get this:

```
[root@node-1 centos]# kubectl cluster-info | grep 'Kubernetes master' | awk '/http/ {print $NF}'
https://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:6443
```

Problem is that we are now trying to create a Kube config file so I can run kubectl from my local machine but my kubectl seems to not be able to reach the kube API

In my kube config, I tried using both the public IP and the DNS name of the EC2 VM but it doesn't work (it times out after a long time)

My firewall on EC2 is open, so that shouldn't be a problem

Any ideas on how I can expose my cluster installed inside EC2 to external world/kubectl?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not the best security practise to expose kubernetes API outside your VPC. If you want to access, you can use a machine in the VPC where the cluster is running and then use your kubeconfig file to connect to your cluster.

Comment: Does AWS security group allow port 6443?

Comment: I understand its not the best security but we need to make it work for this cluster

Comment: Yep, the security group does allow 6443

Comment: Check the firewall one more time. Also check the firewall on linux. Timeout suggests that the packets don't reach the vm and are being dropped somehwhere alond the path. If they were reaching the VM and there were some problems with port bindings you would see connection refused.

Comment: Again, security is not a problem, we even have it allowing all IPs and ports both in and out